# How to handler TCP long connection failover?

Tags: tcp, cluster-computing, failover, apache-mina

I have many servers (cluster) to run same application based TCP long connection(apache mina socket). When one server goes down, how other servers can keep the socket connection, established with the client alive without letting client know of the server down (failure)
Any solution in linux? thanks.

Comment: What does "the client can be unknown to the the server-down failure" mean?

Comment: The server-down failure is transparent to client.the client need not reconnect to server.