# How to handle TCP long connection when one server fail?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, high-availability

I have many linux servers (cluster) to run my application.The application use C/S structure,client connect to server using TCP long connection(server is basing apache mina socket framework).

my question is : When one server shutdown, how other servers can keep the socket connection established between the failure server and the clients? 
so the server-down failure can be transparent to clients and clients need not reconnect to server.

Thanks
L.J.W

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handler TCP long connection failover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080534/how-to-handler-tcp-long-connection-failover)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply migrate a TCP connection unless there is some kind of never-failing proxy in between like a layer-4-switch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Any open source free solution in linux?